# Dev C++ linking libcurl error

Tags: c++, curl, gcc, linker-errors

hmm first i using Dev C++ 5.11, and libcurl 7.49.1 version.
i got this kind of undefined reference error.

> ```
> > C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccvGvYY0.o 123123.cpp:(.text+0x14):
> > undefined reference to `curl_easy_init'
> > [Error] ld returned 1 exit status
> ```

this my code

```
#define CURL_STATICLIB
#include "curl/curl.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void) {
    CURLcode ret;
    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed creating CURL easy handle!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /*Attempt to get twitter*/
    ret = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.twitter.com");
    if (ret != CURLE_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed getting http://www.google.com: %s\n",
                curl_easy_strerror(ret));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    ret = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    if (ret != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed getting http://www.google.com: %s\n",
                curl_easy_strerror(ret));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I tried to do research in google, like to copy **include** folder in **curl** then paste them in  **E:\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\include**

then copy **lib** folder from curl to **E:\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib**

also use this linker

> gcc -Wall -O2 -g -lcurl -o test main.cpp
>
> but it end up with 
>   [Error] gcc: No such file or directory

Comment: try `gcc -Wall -O2 -g \`pkg-config --libs --cflags libcurl\` -o test main.cpp`

Comment: Why is this tagged both `c++` and `c` ?

Comment: stil error unrecognized command line --libs & --cflags, no such files gcc, pkg-config, libcurl.

Comment: Sorry my mistake to tagged that both language.

Comment: the file name clearly indicates this is about a `C++` file, strongly suggest replacing the `c` tag with the `c++` tag, so this question will be routed to those that answer questions about `C++`

Comment: still no solution? :)

Comment: nah it's fine now haha @CBastianelli